# Conditional formating google sheets rows

Tags: google-sheets, colors, conditional-formatting

I would like to change the color of my cells. The problem is the following:
When inserting "Low", "Medium", "High", "Very High" row by row in G3-I3, I want the cells in row L3-O3 to change color depending on the entry. The other table references row 4 and the last one references row 5.

Thanks for your help!

So far I have formatted each cell individually. I wonder if there is a more automated variant. Maybe you can help me with this. I have attached my dummy dataset.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ebyeq8gNTpv1b_4Ly8GKN1Q2yNyIxpdeDdWOf4afOvs/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: what is the input for G3:I3 ?

Comment: "Low", "Medium", "High", "Very High"  and after you entert it the table right from it will change the color. Like "Low" will turn green.